# How to show icons in drawable list in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

During day to day development, many times it is required to check the icons in drawable folder and many icons have similar names, so it is tough to identify icon to use. I have to open icon each time to check it by double click on it.

**So my question:** Is there any way to show icon in drawable list directly without opening it ?
Attaching a screenshot for better visibility.

[image]

Comment: Why someone will ask a question and answer himself just after asking, that is not even programming related? Just curious about the timing of question and answer.

Comment: @Talha, It is a self answered question which is recommended by stackoverflow. Please check this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: I agree, the post does say that, and it is ok to do so, but this is not programming related.

Comment: Use of the Android Studio IDE is programming related and we even have a dedicated tag for it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, I found a solution for this as:

**There is a Android Studio and IntelliJ IDEA plugin that replaces default icons with drawables previews inside project view. (Android drawable preview plugin)**

It just works as we required in this question. Follow below steps to use it.

[image]

**Installation**

- Download plugin zip archive
- Inside Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Install
  plugin from disk
- Select zip archive

  **OR**
- Inside Android Studio go to File -> Settings -> Plugins -> Browse
  repositories
- Search Android Drawable Preview
- Click Install Plugin

This whole information is included in this [**Git Page**](https://github.com/mistamek/Android-drawable-preview-plugin)